# Why is my question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133788/what-other-jewish-born-people-have-the-same-opinion-about-judaism-similarly-to-r) a couple minutes ago, and it got closed within less than a minute after its publication without any reason noted. It is closed as off-topic, but this is a historical question (tagged by it) about Judaism. I asked the justification in a comment in the cited question thread, but it has been left unanswered.

So, can the respective moderator shed some light on this here(!)?

Answer (score 6):

The question you asked was "What other Jewish-born people (among famous figures of art, sports, politics, etc.) have declared the same opinion on 'Judaism as a mere religion rather than a race' similarly to that of Feynman's?"

The fact that someone is born Jewish doesn't give their opinion any special value in Judaism, and hence your question is equivalent, for purpose of this discussion, to "What random people have declared the opinion 'Judaism as a mere religion rather than a race'?"

Moreover, whether Judaism should be described in English as a "religion" or "race" is not an issue that Judaism has or ought have any established opinion on, especially given how ill-defined those English terms are.

I hope that helps you see why I felt this question didn't fit the site guidelines.

If you want to, you can edit the question to clarify a claim that you want to know Judaism's position on, and users here will be happy to provide you with authoritative sources that describe the range of opinions within Judaism on that issue.